# How to stream audio to an android app using PhoneGap

Tags: java, android, cordova, streaming

i need to create an app for Android that streams and internet radio.
The radio streams using mms and http.
I know android supports RTSP (RTP, SDP), HTTP/HTTPS progressive streaming and HTTP/HTTPS live streaming, but i can't understand how to stream them in PhoneGap.
I tried this:

```
<audio controls src="http://source" />
```

And

```
<audio controls src="mms://source" />
```

But nothing appears.
Maybe i need to use java to read the stream?
I didn't find anything useful on google.

Roby

Comment: The audio tag is pretty broken. Try using the Media class instead.

Comment: I already tried, i get an IOException opening the stream.